# iOS - UITableViewCell doesn't reload until I select another cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem reloading selected cells.
Trying to follow a tutorial but now stuck with a strange problem.
I have made a list where selecting an item is suppose to show/remove a checkmark.
However, the cell is not updated until I select another cell in the list.

Any ideas?

I have attached the relevant sourcecode below.

Thanks, K

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListPrototypeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    XYZToDoItem *toDoItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.itemName;

if(toDoItem.completed) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
XYZToDoItem *toDoItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
toDoItem.completed = !toDoItem.completed;
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is tha tha you didn't use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but the `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` so right now every time you deselect your cell you updateyour cell :)

Answer (score 4):

You've accidentally implemented `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.